# How to implement an adapter framework in C++ that works in both Linux and Windows

Tags: c++, templates, dll, cross-platform, shared-libraries

Here is what I am trying to do:

I am developing a cross-platform IDE (Linux and Windows) that supports plug-ins. I need to support extensibility using an adapter framework similar to the one that Eclipse provides. See [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Adapters/index.html) for more details, but basically I need the following:

Let `Adaptee` and `Adapted` be completely unrelated classes which already exist and which we are not allowed to change in any way. I want to create an `AdapterManager` class which has a method

```
template <class Adaptee, class Adapted> Adapted* adapt( Adaptee* object);
```

which will create an instance of `Adapted` given an instance of `Adaptee`. How exactly the instance is created depends on an adapter function which will have to be registered with `AdapterManager`. Each new plug-in should be able to contribute adapter functions for arbitrary types.

Here are my thoughts about a possible solution and why it does not work:

- C++11's RTTI functions and the `type_info` class provide a `hash_code()` method which returns a unique integer for each type in the program. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code). Thus `AdapterManager` could simply contain a map that given the hash codes for the Adaptee and Adapter classes returns a function pointer to the adapter function. This makes the implementation of the `adapt()` function above trivial:

  ```
  template <class Adaptee, class Adapted> Adapted* AdapterManager::adapt( Adaptee* object)
  {
    AdapterMapKey mk( typeid(Adapted).hash_code(), typeid(Adaptee).hash_code());
    AdapterFunction af = adapterMap.get(mk);
    if (!af) return nullptr;
    return (Adapted*) af(object);
  }
  ```

  Any plug-in can easily extend the framework by simply inserting an additional function into the map. Also note that any plug-in can try to adapt any class to any other class and succeed if there exists a corresponding adapter function registered with `AdapterManager` regardless of who registered it.
- A problem with this is the combination of templates and plug-ins (shared objects / DLLs). Since two plug-ins can instantiate a template class with the same parameters, this could potentially lead to two separate instances of the corresponding `type_info` structures and potentially different `hash_code()` results, which will break the mechanism above. Adapter functions registered from one plug-in might not always work in another plug-in.
- In Linux, the dynamic linker seems to be able to deal with multiple declarations of types in different shared libraries under some conditions according to [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#dso) (point 4.2). However the real problem is in Windows, where it seems that each DLL will get its own version of a template instantiation regardless of whether it is also defined in other loaded DLLs or the main executable. The dynamic linker seems quite inflexible compared to the one used in Linux.
- I have considered using explicit template instantiations which seems to reduce the problem, but still does not solve it as two different plug-ins might still instantiate the same template in the same way.

Questions:

1. Does anyone know of a way to achieve this in Windows? If you were allowed to modify existing classes, would this help?
2. Do you know of another approach to achieve this functionality in C++, while still preserving all the desired properties: no change to existing classes, works with templates, supports plug-ins and is cross-platform?

**Update 1:**
This project uses the Qt framework for many things including the plug-in infrastructure. Qt really helps with cross platform development. If you know of a Qt specific solution to the problem, that's also welcome.

**Update 2:**
n.m.'s comment made me realize that I only know about the problem in theory and have not actually tested it. So I did some testing in both Windows and Linux using the following definition:

```
template <class T>
class TypeIdTest {
    public:
        virtual ~TypeIdTest() {};
        static int data;
};
template <class T> int TypeIdTest<T>::data;
```

This class is instantiated in two different shared libraries/DLLs with T=int. Both libraries are explicitly loaded at run-time. Here is what I found:

In *Linux* everything just works:

- The two instantiations used the same *vtable*.
- The object returned by `typeid` was at the same address.
- Even the static data member was the same.
- So the fact that the template was instantiated in multiple dynamically loaded shared libraries made absolutely no difference. The linker seems to simply use the first loaded instantiation and ignore the rest.

In *Windows* the two instantiations are *'somewhat'* distinct:

- The `typeid` for the different instances returns `type_info` objects at different addresses. These objects however are equal when tested with `==`. The corresponding hash codes are also equal. It seems like on Windows equality between types is established using the type's name - which makes sense. So far so good.
- However the *vtables* for the two instances were different. I'm not sure how much of a problem this is. In my tests I was able to use `dynamic_cast` to downcast an instance of `TypeIdTest` to a derived type across shared library boundaries.
- What's also a problem is that each instantiation used its own copy of the static field `data`. That can cause a lot of problems and basically disallows static fields in template classes.

Overall, it seems that even in Windows things are not as bad as I thought, but I'm still reluctant to use this approach given that template instantiations still use distinct *vtables* and static storage. Does anyone know how to avoid this problem? I did not find any solution.

Comment: I think you're trying to solve a runtime problem at compile time. I think in this case inheritance and virtual functions will be more straight forwand and less error prone than templates (because as you noted there's a lot of magic going on in what you're trying to do).

Comment: I think the essence of the problem is that there is no way to get my hands on a unique type identifier (even at run time) that will work across plug-in boundaries. At least that seems to be the case in Windows. I am not sure inheritance and virtual functions will work because each plug-in can contribute new classes which should also be arbitrarily adaptable. Do you have an idea of how it might be done?

Comment: You can't adapt arbirtrary types at compile time from a plugin because you'd need the header file of the said plugin. That defeats the purpose of the plugins, you could just compile everything at the same time.

Obviously you can't adapt arbirtrary types at runtime in C++. On the other hand you can adapt arbitrary types that have the same base class.

If this is not enough, then each plugin must provide a register function that can is called at the beginning of the program that will do the necessary to register all adaptable types and their respective adaptation function.

Comment: Sorry, about that bit where you can't do it, you can, but not in a typesafe way, you'll have to fallback to void*. (Edit: I hope for you someone knows better than I do :/)

Comment: Sorry, again, but my mind works slowly toward a solution. You could have something similar to COM objects. It means implementing your own interfaces and virtual tables. There's something called boost::reflect that may help, https://github.com/bytemaster/boost_reflect, but I have never used it like this.

Comment: (1) There's no `hash_code()` function in the `type_info` class. (2) `typeid` returns a `type_info` object by value, which makes the point of 4.2 completely irrelevant (it talks about comparing `type_info`s by address).

Comment: You can have a look at this question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167707/is-there-a-c-net-java-plugin-framework

Comment: @n.m. Since c++11 `std::type_info` has a `hash_code()` method. See here: [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code)
You can find some more info about it in the new C++ standard doc.

Comment: @J.N. thanks for the suggestion. That other question has a different type of problem though, namely what plug-in infrastructure one should use that allows to mix programming languages. I'm only concerned with C++ and I'm already using Qt to handle plug-ins.

Comment: So what's the problem with the `type_info`? The standard says that two `type_info` objects compare equal iff the corresponding types are "the same". If you worry about two identical template instantiations in different libraries may somehow produce types which are not "the same", you have bigger problems than that. You cannot confidently share `std::string`s or `std::stream`s between dynamic libraries, for one, since they are template instantiations too. Or throw any template-based exceptions across library boundaries. I don't think an implementation that has such problems will go very far.

Answer (score 1):

I think Boost Extension deals with exactly this problem domain:

- http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/index.html

  > (*in preparation for this library's submission to Boost for review*)

In particular you'd be interested in what the author wrote in [this blog post: "Resource Management Across DLL Boundaries](http://blog.redshoelace.com/2009/06/resource-management-across-dll.html):

> RTTI does not always function as expected across DLL boundaries. Check out the type_info classes to see how I deal with that.

I'm not sure whether his solution is actually robust, but he sure gave this thought, before. In fact, there are some samples using Boost Extensions that you can give a go, you might want to use it.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I had a look at Boost Extension, but it it does not seem to provide a solution to my problem. I'm already using Qt (see the updated question) to manage my cross-platform plug-ins infrastructure and it works great. From what I see Boost Extension is just a plug-ins manager framework that provide similar functionality to Qt's plug-ins system.

The problem I have is very specific and neither Qt nor Boost Extension give any details in that regard.